# Hive Server 2 thrift Client error: Required field 'operationHandle' is unset

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, thrift, cloudera

I am trying to run the below hive thrift code on hive server2 on CDH 4.3 and getting below error. Here is my code: I can run  hive jdbc connection to same server successfully, it is just thrift which is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
   TSocket transport = new TSocket("my.org.hiveserver2.com",10000);
   transport.setTimeout(999999999);
   TBinaryProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
   TCLIService.Client client = new TCLIService.Client(protocol);

   transport.open();

   TOpenSessionReq openReq = new TOpenSessionReq();
   TOpenSessionResp openResp = client.OpenSession(openReq);
   TSessionHandle sessHandle = openResp.getSessionHandle();
   TExecuteStatementReq execReq = new TExecuteStatementReq(sessHandle, "SELECT * FROM testhivedrivertable");
   TExecuteStatementResp execResp = client.ExecuteStatement(execReq);
   TOperationHandle stmtHandle = execResp.getOperationHandle();
   TFetchResultsReq fetchReq = new TFetchResultsReq(stmtHandle, TFetchOrientation.FETCH_FIRST, 1);
   TFetchResultsResp resultsResp = client.FetchResults(fetchReq);

   TRowSet resultsSet = resultsResp.getResults();
   List<TRow> resultRows = resultsSet.getRows();
   for(TRow resultRow : resultRows){
       resultRow.toString();
   }

   TCloseOperationReq closeReq = new TCloseOperationReq();
   closeReq.setOperationHandle(stmtHandle);
   client.CloseOperation(closeReq);
   TCloseSessionReq closeConnectionReq = new TCloseSessionReq(sessHandle);
   client.CloseSession(closeConnectionReq);

   transport.close();

}
```

Here is the error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'operationHandle' is unset! Struct:TFetchResultsReq(operationHandle:null, orientation:FETCH_FIRST, maxRows:1)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TFetchResultsReq.validate(TFetchResultsReq.java:465)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$FetchResults_args.validate(TCLIService.java:12607)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$FetchResults_args$FetchResults_argsStandardScheme.write(TCLIService.java:12664)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$FetchResults_args$FetchResults_argsStandardScheme.write(TCLIService.java:12633)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$FetchResults_args.write(TCLIService.java:12584)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:63)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.send_FetchResults(TCLIService.java:487)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.FetchResults(TCLIService.java:479)
        at HiveJDBCServer1.main(HiveJDBCServer1.java:26)
```

Comment: Maybe you can try by: hive --service hiveserver more info [http://leezk.com/tag/hive](http://leezk.com/tag/hive)

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you set the operationsHandle field to a valid value? The Thrift eror indicates what it says: The API expects a certain field (operationHandle in your case) to be set, which has not been assigned a value. And you stack trace confirms this:

> Struct:TFetchResultsReq(**operationHandle:null**, orientation:FETCH_FIRST,
>   maxRows:1)

Comment: @liunkor : I am using hiveserver2, I know hive server1 will work, as I have other app that works fine on hiveserver 1.

Comment: You are right that OperationHandle is not set. That's where I am puzzled why `TOperationHandle stmtHandle = execResp.getOperationHandle();` is not setting operation handle.

Comment: Has anyone successfully build thrift client with HIVERSERVER2.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this, like I did, by googling that error message: I had a similar problem with a PHP Thrift library for hiverserver2.  At least in my case, execResp.getOperationHandle() returned NULL because there was an error in the executed request that generated execResp.  This didn't throw an exception for some reason, and I had to examine execResp in detail, and specifically check the status, before attempting to get an operation handle.